# Como fazer uma animação CSS parar no último estado?

Tags: css, animação

Tenho uma `div`, que é animada, e não gostaria que no final da animação ela volta-se para o estado de quando ela começou, porque ela acaba voltando ao estado original ao final da animação.

```css
#div1 {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:silver;
    position:relative;
    animation-name:animacao;
    animation-duration:3s;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-delay:0.5s;
}
@keyframes animacao {
    from {
        left:0px
    }
    to {
        left:100px
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fauqk0e5/

Comment: O fiddle não faz nenhuma animação, para além de apresentar o quadrado..

Comment: @CesarMiguel Seu browser não deve suportar essas propriedades sem prefixo. Tente http://jsfiddle.net/zb4rfgkk/ no Chrome.

Comment: @bfavaretto exacto, faltava os prefixos

Comment: @Guilherme Beat me by 5s :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Sério? Foi sorte cowboy, você ainda é o mais rápido do oeste kkkk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe uma propriedade experimental chamada [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) que define "como uma animação CSS deve aplicar os estilos ao alvo antes e depois de sua execução". O valor `forwards` determina que o elemento retenha os estilos do último *keyframe* da animação.

Aplicando isso, com o prefixo `-webkit` para todas as propriedades, seu CSS ficaria assim:

```
#div1 {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:silver;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name:animacao;
    -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animacao {
    from {
        left:0px
    }
    to {
        left:100px
    }
}
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/dp3ywmw9/</sup>

Mas atenção: o código com esse prefixo só funcionará em browsers que aceitam esse prefixo. É recomendável incluir todos os prefixos além de uma versão não prefixada (ou usar algum JS que faça isso para você).

Comment: Bom ter comentando que ele retêm o último keyframe da animação, pois se eu faço uma animação com varios keyframes, 10%,20%,.. ele não acumula e simplesmente para no final, ele apenas retêm o ultimo keyframe e pausa a animação nele.

Comment: Acho que talvez, o mais ideal seria rodar a animação com JS e no fim pausá-la no último estado

Answer (score 2):

Podes adicionar a propriedade `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` para não voltar a posição incial:

```
#div1 {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:silver;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name:animacao;
    -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
@-webkit-keyframes animacao {
    from {
        left:0px
    }
    to {
        left:100px
    }
}
```

Comment: Postamos a mesma coisa quase ao mesmo tempo!

Comment: Estava a fazer uns teste nos browsers a ver se ficava bem em todos, porém foste 15 segundos mais rápido, mas com uma resposta bem detalhada :) +1

Comment: @bfavaretto Mas os prefixos do Cesar parecem estar errados, o certo não deveria ser assim `-webkit-*` ao invés de `webkit-*`?

Comment: É verdade, @GuilhermeNascimento